# Electronic reporting automation and bank reconciliation (BAI2)

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have to submit BAI2 files for bank reconciliation that are coming in from a logic app into the DMF. I have found that the DMF is no longer used, but I cannot change the way the file comes in as that is handled by an external team. I have created an entity to store the BAI2 file in a raw format.

How can I submit this using x++ to the Electronic Reporting framework as a BAI2 file? Does the GER support BAI2 files? Is there even code to submit files automatically to the GER framework?

My current solution converts the records received into DMF from the external logic app back into a .txt file and stores it in the temp blob storage(or on the local aos server in c:\windows\temp - both are an option). So I have the .txt file as a stream to submit it in any way possible to the GER, but I cannot find a way to do this and there doesn't appear to be documentation on automated GER code.

Comment: Maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/analytics/er-configure-data-import-sharepoint and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/analytics/er-apis-app73#code-to-run-a-format-mapping-for-data-import are helpful?

Comment: Second link is an excellent resource. I found I can just get a SharedServiceUnitFileID from a stream object (save the file/stream into the temp blob that returns a file id) and submit the file id to the BankStatementImportBatch class. However, the ER is not that robust "out of the box" and requires a lot of customization to the report which is not ideal. Looking into a custom solution that doesn't use ER.

Comment: I'm currently looking into enabling the bank statement entities as OData endpoints and then use those to get the data into the system. Prototype works, but of course, in your case you would need some solution that transforms the BAI2 file into the JSON format required by the OData endpoints.